# How to index a pandas dataframe by datetime?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-pandas

I am using the django_pandas package to obtain a Pandas dataframe from stored Django models.

```
df = qs.to_dataframe(['time', 'price_open', 'price_high', 'price_low', 'price_close'], index='time')
```

Now I want to access the dataframe by a datetime, however, this does not work. Printing df looks like this, where the time column has a weird position: [image: printing the df]

If I do `print(df.keys())` I get the following results: Index(['price_open', 'price_high', 'price_low', 'price_close', ], dtype='object') but I more expected time. Also, df.columns does not contain time but only the other columns.

How can I access df by a given datetime? Why is time not the key for df? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a call to reset_index(). Also, make sure the data being loaded is actually being read as datetime, you can manually specify this when you read the csv

Comment: thanks, df=df.reset_index() helped.
However, now I want to resample the dataframe and use: dailyFrame=df.resample('D').agg({'price_open': 'first', 'price_high': 'max', 'price_low': 'min', 'price_close': 'last'})

Now I get the error "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'" - which I did not get before. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ThePorcius, `reset_index` should give you back the time column.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), you can use `on` argument in `resample` to use a column instead of index.
You'll need to make sure that `time` column is a `datetime`.

```
dailyFrame=(
    df.resample('D', on='time')
    .agg({'price_open': 'first', 'price_high': 'max', 'price_low': 'min', 'price_close': 'last'})
)
```